# Android mkdir() can't make folder inside root of removable micro SD-card

Tags: android, kotlin

I use this code to get folder of removable SD-card:

```
var baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath
val dirs = getExternalFilesDirs(null)
for (file in dirs){
    if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(file)) {
        baseDir = file.absolutePath
        val idx = baseDir.indexOf("/Android/")
        if(idx > 0) {
            baseDir = baseDir.substring(0,idx)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And it work well enough, at least on test devices. After this code `baseDir` contain something like `/storage/AB96-CD85`. But when I try to make dir, I always get false result:

```
baseDir = baseDir + java.io.File.separator + name
var result: File? = null

if (Environment.getExternalStorageState() != Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {
    Log.e(TAG, "SD-card not mounted.")
    return result
 }
 val dir = File(baseDir)
 if (!dir.exists()) {
     if (!dir.mkdir()) {
         Log.e(
                TAG,
                "Can't create directory $name"
            )
         return result
     }
 }
```

minSdkVersion is 21. Before this code execution I've already requested `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and got positive response from user. I wrote permission block in Manifest in correct place (out of `<application></application>` block). The code above create folder without any problems on one device and cannot do the same on other (in the same time ES File manager work well on sdcard). What was tried:

1. App re-installation
2. Phone restart
3. Even unplag USB cable
4. Storage Access Framework(SAF)

What I should do to make `mkdir()` function work on the second device? 
If I should add some other permission or move user to some system settings screen, how can I do that? 
Why code above work on one device and doesn't work on other?

Comment: You do not have [read-write access to arbitrary locations on removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). You will have even less access to the filesystem on Android Q and beyond. I **strongly** recommend that you use the Storage Access Framework (i.e., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`).

Comment: It doesn't answer the question why it work on one device

Comment: @CommonsWare and does SAF give me ability to write in the root of removable sdcard? Why third-party apps like ES filemanager and MX video player can write/delete files in sdcard?

Comment: "and does SAF give me ability to write in the root of removable sdcard?" -- if the user chooses it, yes. "Why third-party apps like ES filemanager and MX video player can write/delete files in sdcard?" -- perhaps they are using SAF. MX might be using `MediaStore`.

Comment: @CommonsWare no, SAF doesn't work too. I'm able to write with SAF or old fashion way in `SD-CARD-NAME/Android/data/appID/files/` but in the root `SD-CARD-NAME/`

Comment: @Raskilas Did you solve your issue? Because I have the same problem, I can't create directory into the root of USB pen

Comment: @EmanueleLeoni no, in those case nothing helped me nor SAF or old fashion way. If you would need to save file, then use system wide available folders like Downloads or DCIM. Or use your app's data/obb folder. On newer Android (10-12) clear access to filesystem cutted out(fully or partly).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about different `Android` versions.
To modify External SD card's filesystem, you need to get "special permision".
You can Google some libraries, that do it automatically. Just use one of these and you will gain that "special permission". It's weird but `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` not providing you access to SD Card, only to eMMC memory.

Comment: I may thought that this because I used old fashion way to create a folder, but the fact is that code work on one device and doesn't work on other + third-party apps work on both devices. Why MX video player can write/delete files on sdcard and my app not?

Comment: @Raskilas I think `Android` unserstands, for which version your app builded up. Try to change it.

Comment: what do you mean? minSdk is 21, so app support android since 5.0 and it is minimal what I need.